# RavenDB can't perform search with AND operator on nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, search, nosql, ravendb

How can I perform a search with 'AND' operator via RavenDB?

Based on the docs it's written that I need to add the operator enum ("AND" \ "OR") as the third parameter of the search function.
https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.0/nodejs/client-api/session/querying/how-to-use-search

From some reason the AND operator does not work and it gives me OR results by default.

Example:

Users collection:

```
users/1-A: {
    firstName: 'Joe',
    lastName: 'Allen'
}

users/2-A: {
    firstName: 'Joe',
    lastName: 'Biden'
}
```

The call to raven:

```
session.query({ collection: 'Users' })
.search('firstName', 'Joe', 'AND') // search with AND operator
.search('lastName', 'Biden')
.all()
```

The call above returns back both documents.
What should be the appropriate syntax for that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can find detailed examples & walkthrough explanations in the following **RavenDB demos**:

https://demo.ravendb.net/demos/csharp/text-search/fts-query-search-basics
https://demo.ravendb.net/demos/csharp/text-search/fts-query-search-operators

So this here above is currently only for C# client (nodeJS demos are TBD)

**When using 2 separate search methods**:
Then the other answer here - about using `andAlso` - is correct

**When using single search method**:
Using `AND/OR` is relevant only when you have **2 or more terms within the same search method**.

i.e.:
`.search('firstName', 'John Doe', 'AND')`
will AND both terms (John && Doe)

`.search('firstName', 'John Doe', 'OR')` 
will OR the results (John || Doe)

Comment: I found  a solution for Node.js using the `andAlso` function. Check out my answer

Comment: I updated my above answer as well

Answer (score 3):

So I found a solution for node.js.
The `"AND"` enum as a third parameter did not work for me (according to this page: https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.0/nodejs/client-api/session/querying/how-to-use-search).

I foundo another page:
https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.0/nodejs/indexes/querying/searching

Which uses `andAlso()` function on the query to use the `"AND"` operator and it works.

Example:

```
const joeBiden = session.query({ collection: 'Users' })
.search('firstName', 'Joe')
.andAlso()
.search('lastName', 'Biden')
.all()
```

This will return only Joe Biden's document.

Please note that it returns a promise.

** Raven will raise an error if you call the `andAlso` function and no query after it, so if you loop through possible search terms remember to exclude the `andAlso` function in the last search.

```
const joeBiden = session.query({ collection: 'Users' })
    .search('firstName', 'Joe')
    .andAlso()
    .search('lastName', 'Biden')
    .andAlso() // this line will cause Raven to throw an error
    .all()
```